# How to extract matrix which produces given symbolic linear combinations?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Suppose I have a column matrix $\alpha$, consisting of some symbols

```
a[0,0]
a[0,1]
a[0,2]
a[0,3]
a[1,0]
a[1,1]
a[1,2]
a[1,3]
a[2,0]
a[2,1]
a[2,2]
a[2,3]
a[3,0]
a[3,1]
a[3,2]
a[3,3]
```

and a column matrix $x$, consisting of linear combinations of symbols above

```
a[0,0]
a[0,0]+a[1,0]+a[2,0]+a[3,0]
a[0,0]+a[0,1]+a[0,2]+a[0,3]
a[0,0]+a[0,1]+a[0,2]+a[0,3]+a[1,0]+a[1,1]+a[1,2]+a[1,3]+a[2,0]+a[2,1]+a[2,2]+a[2,3]+a[3,0]+a[3,1]+a[3,2]+a[3,3]
a[1,0]
a[1,0]+2 a[2,0]+3 a[3,0]
a[1,0]+a[1,1]+a[1,2]+a[1,3]
a[1,0]+a[1,1]+a[1,2]+a[1,3]+2 a[2,0]+2 a[2,1]+2 a[2,2]+2 a[2,3]+3 a[3,0]+3 a[3,1]+3 a[3,2]+3 a[3,3]
a[0,1]
a[0,1]+a[1,1]+a[2,1]+a[3,1]
a[0,1]+2 a[0,2]+3 a[0,3]
a[0,1]+2 a[0,2]+3 a[0,3]+a[1,1]+2 a[1,2]+3 a[1,3]+a[2,1]+2 a[2,2]+3 a[2,3]+a[3,1]+2 a[3,2]+3 a[3,3]
a[1,1]
a[1,1]+2 a[2,1]+3 a[3,1]
a[1,1]+2 a[1,2]+3 a[1,3]
a[1,1]+2 a[1,2]+3 a[1,3]+2 a[2,1]+4 a[2,2]+6 a[2,3]+3 a[3,1]+6 a[3,2]+9 a[3,3]
```

then how may I extract matrix $A$ of coefficients so that

$A \alpha = x$

I.e. I need to know all coefficients from linear combinations $x$.

Later I wish to know matrix it's inverse, which should be

[image]

The answer should not rely on the pattern of `a[i,j]`, symbols may be any, for example 16 of `a, b, c, d, ...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CoefficientArrays`:

```
xx = {a[0, 0], a[0, 0] + a[1, 0] + a[2, 0] + a[3, 0], a[0, 0] + a[0, 1] + a[0, 2] + a[0, 3], 
   a[0, 0] + a[0, 1] + a[0, 2] + a[0, 3] + a[1, 0] + a[1, 1] + 
    a[1, 2] + a[1, 3] + a[2, 0] + a[2, 1] + a[2, 2] + a[2, 3] + 
    a[3, 0] + a[3, 1] + a[3, 2] + a[3, 3], a[1, 0], 
   a[1, 0] + 2 a[2, 0] + 3 a[3, 0], a[1, 0] + a[1, 1] + a[1, 2] + a[1, 3], 
   a[1, 0] + a[1, 1] + a[1, 2] + a[1, 3] + 2 a[2, 0] + 2 a[2, 1] + 
    2 a[2, 2] + 2 a[2, 3] + 3 a[3, 0] + 3 a[3, 1] + 3 a[3, 2] + 
    3 a[3, 3], a[0, 1], a[0, 1] + a[1, 1] + a[2, 1] + a[3, 1], 
   a[0, 1] + 2 a[0, 2] + 3 a[0, 3], 
   a[0, 1] + 2 a[0, 2] + 3 a[0, 3] + a[1, 1] + 2 a[1, 2] + 3 a[1, 3] +
     a[2, 1] + 2 a[2, 2] + 3 a[2, 3] + a[3, 1] + 2 a[3, 2] + 
    3 a[3, 3], a[1, 1], a[1, 1] + 2 a[2, 1] + 3 a[3, 1], 
   a[1, 1] + 2 a[1, 2] + 3 a[1, 3], 
   a[1, 1] + 2 a[1, 2] + 3 a[1, 3] + 2 a[2, 1] + 4 a[2, 2] + 
    6 a[2, 3] + 3 a[3, 1] + 6 a[3, 2] + 9 a[3, 3]};

alpha = {a[0, 0], a[0, 1], a[0, 2], a[0, 3], a[1, 0], a[1, 1], 
   a[1, 2], a[1, 3], a[2, 0], a[2, 1], a[2, 2], a[2, 3], a[3, 0], 
   a[3, 1], a[3, 2], a[3, 3]};

aA = Normal[CoefficientArrays[xx, alpha]][[2]]
```

Verify that `aA.alpha` gives `xx`:

```
aA.alpha == xx
(* True *)
```

Use `Inverse[aA]` to get the inverse:

```
Row[MatrixForm /@ {aA, Inverse[aA]}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Comment: ... The inverse matrix does not match the inverse matrix in the picture posted by the OP.

Comment: this is probably because of the different order of coefficients

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a more "mathy" approach:

Assuming `xx` and `alpha` are defined as in kguler's answer,

```
A = D[xx, {alpha}]
```

which produces identical output.  I like thinking in this way because it is useful for computing [hessians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) (in a slightly different context).

Comment: ++1 wish i could think of this approach:)

Comment: : )

I should say that I think `D` take a little bit longer for this example.  Haven't put in the work to figure out if it's a constant factor or if the performance difference scales.